# React + Redux. Какую библиотеку или компонент выбрать для локализации?

Tags: reactjs, локализация, redux, перевод

- Желательно достаточно популярную среди русскоязычного сообщества.
- Перевод констант для текущего языка.
- Перевод пути роутера.
- Перевод интерфейса в зависимости от логики перевода (если мужчина такое-то
  окончание, если такой падеж, такое окончание).
- Встроенный перевод даты и валюты и пр.

Comment: Хоть вопрос и несколько оффтопичен для so, яростно плюсую, я бы тоже такое хотел

Comment: Также добавлю что при качественной локализации просто сменой констант в словарике не отделаешься, всякие флюгегехаймены будут рушить верстку, а для читающих справа налево ваш дизайн будет крив. Но для локализации с русского на украинский возможно и либа какая найдется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на безрыбье - [react-intl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl), вполне сойдет